# JQuery AJAX Content not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am pretty new to JQuery/Ajax; this really is just my second project, and is my first post here.  I've looked around here quite a bit and am just not coming up with the answer.  The format of the syntax below is similar to what I am successfully using with the Wunderground API.  I assumed this would follow a similar solution.  I am calling out to The Guardian Public API this time.  I can tell data is being returned because when I add #newsitem to my html doc, I see ten iterations of my labels Article, URL and Date, but there is no content showing in my DIV.  I can also see the content when I Inspect in the browser tools.

I am sure I am searching the result array incorrectly or my syntax isn't right.  I didn't post the HTML, but yes, I loaded the JQuery module.

Any help is appreciated.  Sorry if this is a repost - I have looked at every "similar questions" link in the sidebar; hopefully this is easy enough.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://content.guardianapis.com/search?section=us-news&api-key=xxxxx&format=xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(mynews){
        $(mynews).find('response results result').each(function() {
            var strTitle = $(this).find('web-title').text();
            var strUrl = $(this).find('web-url').text();
            var strPubdate = $(this).find('web-publication-date').text();

            $('#newsitem ul').append(
                $('<li />', {
                    text: 'Article: ' + strTitle
                })
            );
            $('#newsitem ul').append(
                $('<li />', {
                    text: 'URL: ' + strUrl
                })
            );          
            $('#newsitem ul').append(
                $('<li />', {
                    text: 'Date: ' + strPubdate
                })
            );
        });

    },
    error: function() {
      $(".newsitem").html('<p>Error: ' + error + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Display Page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Guardian News</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="guardiannews.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">     
        .newsitem li{
            font-family:  Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Guardian News</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="newsitem"><ul><!-- News Content--></ul></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is some sample output from the API.

```
<response status="ok" user-tier="developer" total="30070" current-page="1" pages="15035" start-index="1" page-size="2" order-by="newest">
<results>
<result web-url="https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/jun/14/orlando-shooting-omar-mateen-motive-pulse-nightclub" type="article" section-id="us-news" web-title="FBI to investigate if Orlando gunman's sexuality was a motive in shooting" api-url="https://content.guardianapis.com/us-news/2016/jun/14/orlando-shooting-omar-mateen-motive-pulse-nightclub" section-name="US news" web-publication-date="2016-06-14T19:23:16Z" id="us-news/2016/jun/14/orlando-shooting-omar-mateen-motive-pulse-nightclub"/>
<result web-url="https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/jun/14/donald-trump-muslim-americans-syrian-refugees-fact-check" type="article" section-id="us-news" web-title="Fact-checking Donald Trump's speech in the wake of the Orlando terror attack" api-url="https://content.guardianapis.com/us-news/2016/jun/14/donald-trump-muslim-americans-syrian-refugees-fact-check" section-name="US news" web-publication-date="2016-06-14T19:19:17Z" id="us-news/2016/jun/14/donald-trump-muslim-americans-syrian-refugees-fact-check"/>
</results>
</response>
```

Comment: So does `console.log($("#newsitem ul").length);` return `1`?

Comment: Well, there is a 10 in a highlighted oval next to the number 1 in the console line.  This seems to correspond to the records returned, because if I set the return set to 5, this number changes.  Immediately next to it is a 1, yes.

Comment: So is there CSS hiding the DIV, UL or LIs from view?

Comment: This is the only style I am using so far:

        <style type="text/css">     
  .newsitem li{
   font-family:  Verdana, sans-serif;
   font-size: small;
  }
</style>

Comment: Add it to your question... Add basic html to your question too

Comment: if you inspect the pages html do you see anything there like empty li tags?

Comment: I have modified my question - I appreciate the step-by-step.  I am learning the tools of using this site, so my apologies for making you suffer.  @terpinmnd, when I inspect the elements yes, the LI only shows my labels.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, just a suggestion for when you to do get this working.  first append all the bits to a text string in your loop, the append one time at the end to the UL.  saves loads of screen draw time.

Comment: Thank you @AndyKillen; good to know!

Comment: Can you post an sample response from the API? `<response><results><result>...</result>` etc. Adds detail to the question. **Nevermind** [found it](http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=test&format=xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had a look at the [API in question](http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=test&format=xml), the values you are after are merely attributes of the element node.

You can access these attributes directly using [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), as opposed to your usage of `find()`, like so:

```
var strTitle = $(this).attr('web-title'),
    strUrl = $(this).attr('web-url'),
    strPubdate = $(this).attr('web-publication-date');
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mcz0xq1/).

Comment: That did it!  Thank you!  Again, thanks to everyone for their help - a lot of little helpful pieces of information came in along the way, and I learned how to make a more meaningful post.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of suggestions.

If strTitle, strUrl and strPubdate have correct values, try appending them to the list in a different way, for example:

```
$("#newsitem ul").append($("<li>").text('Article: ' + strTitle));
```

According to your HTML, the newsitem is an id of the div, so should always be used as #newsitem in jQuery selectors. However, in your css and in the error handler you are using ".newsitem" which assumes that newsitem is a class name instead of the id.

Comment: Very helpful, I see what you mean and have cleaned this up and made it consistent.